# Copy all ini from one folder for all users to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy all .ini files from the Windows folder into a new folder I have already created. I need this to loop through for all users. Here is what I have but it only works for the last user, not each of them. This is a batch file.

```
for /r  %%f  in ("D:\Home\*.*\windows") do 
set dir="%%d
for /r "%dir%\windows\" %%f in (*.ini) do (
copy %%f "%dir%\temp_ini"
))
pause
```

Please help :/ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems -- unterminated quote on the second line, not delaying the expansion of `%dir%` (and indeed, setting `%dir%` is unnecessary, anyway), illogical use of `for /r` in the first line, trying to recycle `%%f` in nested loops, and your `*.*` wildcard in the first line will only match directories containing a dot.  You should also make sure the `temp_ini` directory is outside the scope of your search for ini files; otherwise, Windows will attempt to copy the contents of `temp_ini\*.ini` into itself recursively.  Try this instead:

```js
for /d %%I in ("D:\Home\*") do (

    rem // create directory if not exist
    if not exist "%%~I\temp_ini" md "%%~I\temp_ini"

    rem // capture the output of dir /s /b
    for /F "delims=" %%x in (

        'dir /s /b "%%~fI\Windows\*.ini" 2^>NUL'

    ) do copy /y "%%~fx" "%%~I\temp_ini\"
)
pause
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't know if its because the temp_ini directory already exists but this just blinks and is over in half a second.

Comment: temp_ini is in the user folder same spot as the  windows folder.

Comment: When troubleshooting, don't just double-click your script to execute it.  Open a cmd prompt and run your script from the command line.  That way you can see any errors.

Comment: States directory already exists and bombs. So I remove the if not exist line and it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Jordan I just updated my code.  Give it a shot now.

Comment: The second part of what I am doing is appending a text file to the end of the .ini's in the windows folder. However I only want to append it to the files in the windows folder not any of the ini's in its sub directories. I have the code written but it writes to all .ini files in all folders. Is there an indicator I can use to make it not do the sub directories?

Comment: If you want to append the line to the original, do `if /I "%%~fx"=="%%~fI\Windows\%%~nxx" >>"%~fx" echo item=value`.  If only to the copy within temp_ini, do `if /I "%%~fx"=="%%~fI\Windows\%%~nxx" >>"%~I\temp_ini\%%~nxx" echo item=value`